# Infer in conditional types doesn't work with base interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `... extends BaseI<infer A>` in a conditional type, but it doesn't work against classes that implement `BaseI` from actually implementing a `ChildI`:

```js
const T = Symbol();

interface BaseI<T> {
  [T]?: T;
}
interface ChildI<T> extends BaseI<T> {
  name: T;
  [T]?: T;
}
type Mark<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends BaseI<infer A> ? { foo: A } : { foo: number };
};

class ChildImpl<T> implements ChildI<T> {
  name!: T;
}
const obj = {} as Mark<{ child: ChildImpl<string> }>;
const e: string = obj.child.foo;
```

I get a compile error that `child.foo` is a `number` instead of a `string`, i.e. the conditional type did not work.

Comment: `X implements Y` means X provides everything Y says it will have. `ChildI<T>` is just an *interface*, so it doesn't actually provide anything, it just defines what an implementation would provide. `ChildImpl` still has to actually *provide* it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess b/c both `BaseI` and `ChildI` are ~marker interfaces, pushing the `[T]?` symbol hint down into `ChildImpl` itself allows TypeScript realize that "it's the same `T`" and the `extends BaseI` now works:

```js
class ChildImpl<T> implements ChildI<T> {
  name!: T;
  [T]?: T;
}
```

Comment: [That doesn't seem to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKjAvDAygTwLYCMQBsAUAlANwBQpAlmFAKYBOAZgIbA0wBCTENAkgDxwAfDADepGDADacALoB+AFzwyAX0rV6zVjADCACwq4AJvyEwaAD1pgjEDl14DhYiWCYYaSuGQnT5X1VIoNAAHNgBZJjoAayckUXEpAGkYKhhomjQQBngZL0kkmXMrGhs7Tm5+KgZ6GABBYTlRGAYQECU6mBUYJREWtqUwAFdsWpVVMlJgXC47fUMTDBDcOIol3BoPajmDY1NnRLcPAEIAxL9FZVI1UEhYECwAK3iRbq4YSJi+PuBdoyV5nt1nxoHQqABzYQqQRkW7QcxKUEQ+IPR4AOl+CzRrRAxCAA), TypeScript says "A computed property name cannot reference a type parameter from its containing type.(2467)"